# VBA find last occurrence of a string

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to work this problem out for a few days now and I just can't get my head around it. I have searched multiple websites (Even here several times), I have seen that many people have asked this question but the solutions don't work for me.

I want to find the last occurrence of a string in a range and store the address in a variable and display a message telling me where it is.

So far I have this

```
Private Sub CmdBtnClockIt_Click()
  Dim job As String
  Dim searchTerm as Range

  job = CmbBoxJob.Value
  searchTerm = Range("A1:A999").find(what:=job, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
  MsgBox "last cell is " & searchTerm.Address
End Sub
```

All I seem to get is either "invalid qualifier" or "object variable or with block variable not set"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: searchTerm is a Range and needs to be set and not just assigned. `Set searchTerm = .....etc....`

Comment: As @NickSlash mentioned, you need to use Set to return a Range. Also you are using the .Column property at the end, which would return the Column number rather than a Range. You need to leave off the .Column.

Comment: Why do you have searchTerm returning a column? You know already it'll be "1" (which is column A).  Just remove that part of the code (the .column).  Then just put "Set" before "searchTerm - Range(..." and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @user3578951 This gives me an error "object variable or with block variable not set"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first issue is that `searchTerm` is defined as a `Range` object. You must set object assignments using the [`Set` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264263.aspx). So the assignment becomes `Set searchTerm = Range("A1:A999")...`

Secondly, you will hit error messages if the `searchTerm` is not found, because `searchTerm` will be assigned a value of `Nothing`. We can avoid this issue by using a simple condition to check if the `job` was found.

Therefore your updated `Sub` may look something like this:

```
Private Sub CmdBtnClockIt_Click()
  Dim job As String
  Dim searchTerm As Range

  job = CmbBoxJob.Value
  Set searchTerm = Range("A1:A999").Find(what:=job, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
  If searchTerm Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Text was not found"
  Else
    MsgBox "Last cell is " & searchTerm.Address
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This has helped a bit, It keeps returning "Text was not found" So searchTerm isn't being set

Comment: @AshWood: Try a breakpoint or `MsgBox job` after the line `job = CmbBoxJob.Value`. Is the value what you expect? Either `CmbBoxJob.Value` does not have your search term, or the value is never found in the range you specified.

Comment: Thank you, I have got it sorted finally! Your answer helped me a alot

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim job As String
    Dim searchTerm As Range
    job = "Happiness"
    Set searchTerm = Range("A1:A999").Find(what:=job, after:=Range("A1"), searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    MsgBox "last cell is " & searchTerm.Address
End Sub
```

[image]

*Notice I used **Set***.

Comment: This also gives me an error of "object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: For my code and data this means that there is no *Happiness* in column **A**

Comment: Thank you, your answer did help point me in the right direction